# How to change Font-Size of asp.net DropDownList

Tags: css, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have the following `dropdownlist`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="MeetingTypesDS" CssClass="ddl" Font-Size="35px"  DataTextField="MeetingType" DataValueField="MeetingTypeID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("MeetingTypeID") %>'>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

and the css is

```
.ddl {
   width: 300px;
   height: 50px;
   font-size: 30px;
}
```

As you can see I have the Font-Size inline and in the css class. I have tried it without inline and I have tried removing the height and the width from the css class. But the Font-Size of the `dropdownlist` is never changed.

I am trying to make the row part of the drop down part bigger. I could not see anyway to do that so I thought I would adjust the Font-Size but it is not adjusting.

If you inspect the element it shows that the font-size for the class is there, just no change.

I have just discovered that the font-size for the selected item is being changed but no the list values which is what I am after.

Does anyone have any solutions of how to do this.

I thought maybe I could write a class for a part of the dropdown. I am not quite sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is the css class

```
.ddl option  {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```